# Chrome dev tools, preserve HTML edits on refresh of page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am changing the CSS path on a live page to point to my local. I'm sure I've seen before that you can keep the HTML edits in the "Elements" panel when refreshing the page, but I can't find it online. Is this possible?

Otherwise, is there the option of refreshing the CSS file in Dev tools, and not the whole page?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you looked into something like Emmet Livestyle? It should provide the effect you're looking for http://livestyle.emmet.io/

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing this with https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors

Comment: Thanks @JoshRutherford I looked into Emmet Livestyle - it looks promising. 

Nit thanks for your reply, that wasn't quite what I was looking for, but I did need to setup the pre-processor SASS stuff and that tutorial was useful!